# Prettier formatter: any risk?

Tags: javascript, prettier

Is there any potential for regression when running Prettier on all files in an existing project?

Theoretically, since it only does formatting, this should be a zero-risk operation. Is this actually the case?

(I want to run it on a TypeScript React project)

Comment: Hard to say. It shouldn't change the semantics of the program. However, if you have any other linter that watches out for format and its configuration is not synced up with Prettier, you might end up with code that can never be properly formatted because at least one tool will say the format is wrong.

Comment: Well, there are [348 open bugs](//github.com/prettier/prettier/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3Atype%3Abug).

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you. My question is assuming that the project will be configured to be formatted by Prettier alone

Comment: We can't answer this question for you objectively, it's really a judgement call. Your best bet is probably to look through those 348 bugs @SebastianSimon pointed out and see whether any of them causes actual code errors (**very** unlikely to remain unfixed for long) or if they're primarily config not working right or mis-formatting. Then it's up to your team whether to adopt it or not. I suspect tens of thousands of programmers (possibly hundreds of thousands) use Prettier in React projects, which speaks well for it.